Why is performing boolean faster on int as compared to bool
Consider the following code:
class Solution {
public:
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        int sum = 0;
        for (const auto &x: nums) sum += x;
        if (sum % 2) return false;

        vector<int> dp(sum/2+1, false);
        dp[0] = true;

        for(int idx=n-1;idx>=0;idx--) {
            for(int t=sum/2;t>0;t--) {
                if (nums[idx] <= t)
                    dp[t] = dp[t] || dp[t-nums[idx]];
            }
        }

        return dp[sum / 2];
    }
};

which is a solution for this Leetcode problem.
Since the values in the dp vector can take only 2 values, 1 or 0, I tried changing the type of that vector from vector<int> to vector<bool>. Although the code still works perfectly fine and all test cases pass completely, but there is something interesting that happens. Doing this simple change increases the run time of this code from an average of 30-40ms to almost 250-300ms. An increase of almost 7-8x.
What is the reason for this? From preliminary search on the internet, I am guessing it could be something to do with unaligned memory access but I am not sure why exactly this is happening.
[EDIT 1]: The same results can be replicated locally as well:
Consider the following main function:

int main() {
  vector<int> q(1000);
  for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    q[i] = (i*10+7)%201 + 2;
  }

  Solution s;
  cout << s.canPartition(q) << endl;
  return 0;
}

I am using the g++ to compile and the time utility to test the time taken to execute the program:

With vector<int>



With vector<bool>



vector<bool> is "special" in that it packs bytes into bits. that comes with performance cost.  There should be duplicates about it.

And as @NathanOliver says, std::vector behaves differently each bit is accessed through an iterator proxy that will perform extra operations to get individual bits out

Try vector<char> instead. That's sometimes recommended if you want to save space without introducing the 'bit twiddling' that vector<bool> implies.
